# Upgrading Ubuntu 18.04.1 disabled JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I just upgraded to 18.04.1 and trying to adjust to the changes. One huge issue I'm having is that opening a java application, the Ardor client, I get the error "JavaFX not supported". I tried to reinstall OpenJFX and it says it's up to date. Has it somehow become disabled?